# Stop SIP SUBSCRIBEs from endpoint

Tags: sip, publish-subscribe, endpoint

I am working with SIP protocol, and I have an issue with an endpoint (ZTE). The endpoint sends a lot of SUBSCRIBE method messages and I want to stop that because i don't whant to implement it.
I already tried to respond with 403 (Method Forbibben) and 405 (Method Not Allowed), but the endpoint is still sending SUBSCRIBE.

What is the propper way to stop an endpoint to send that method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a 405 (Method not allowed) response is correct. You should also add an Allow header with the methods you DO support.

Omit the SUBSCRIBE method from the Allow headers in (all) your requests and responses to the endpoint. This indicates that you don't support the SUBSCRIBE method.

Of course, you can't control whether the endpoint complies. If it's poorly implemented it could still send SUBSCRIBEs despite you indicating not to send them.

Comment: The Allow header does not contains SUBSCRIBE. Dispite of that, the endpoint is still sending me the message. I tested with a softphone (zoiper) and it has the same behaviour, but it stop sending me subscribes when i respond with a 503 (Forbibben).
I accept this response as the correct because I believe that the procedure my UAS is doing is ok and this answer confirms that.

Answer (score 1):

A well-behaved UAC should inspect the `Allow-Event` header in any response and only subscribe to those event packages listed in the header. If there is no `Allow-Event` header, or an empty value, the assumption should be that the UAS does not support any event package.

Try to include an empty `Allow-Event` header in the preceding response.